# Python : how to close the userpref window?

Tags: python, interface

I want to add a cancel button to quit the userpref window,but it seems no such api to do this thing.How can I solve the problem with Python?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Preference Window is a temporary window attached to the main window with one area of type 'Preferences' only.

So first identify all temporary windows by window.screen.is_temporary and check the area.type. Next you need to override the context as the button or script is called from the main window. With Blender 3.2. there was a change for the context override, so a switch was used here (tested 2.9.3, 3.6.7, 4.0.1).

```
import bpy

def close_pref_window():
    from bpy import context
    pref = False 

    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:  # loop windows
        screen = window.screen
        if not screen.is_temporary:                    # search temporary windows
            continue

        for area in screen.areas:
            if not area.type == 'PREFERENCES':         # search area Preferences
                continue

            if bpy.app.version >= (3, 2, 0):           # override Blender 3.2+
               with context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                   bpy.ops.wm.window_close() 
     
            else:                                      # override Blender < 3.2                
                override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
                bpy.ops.wm.window_close(override)               

            pref = True
            break

    return "preference window closed" if pref else "no preference window found"

# testcall
print(close_pref_window())
```

Comment: Oh , it's works !  Now I learn the usage of  temporary window and window_close , thanks !